# How to get text from an Xpath above the selected one?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract numbers from each table row using Scrapy.

```
     <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">1</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Corners</td>
        <td class="legend right value">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">2</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Shots on target</td>
        <td class="legend right value">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">3</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Shots wide</td>
        <td class="legend right value">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">14</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Fouls</td>
        <td class="legend right value">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">2</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Offsides</td>
        <td class="legend right value">4</td>
      </tr>
```

I have tried many different versions of the code below but till now nothing has returned anything, with no errors being given.

P.S this is just a sample of what I will have later as part of the testing.

```
corners = hxs.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'Corners')]")
stats ["corners"] = corners.xpath("../td[@class = 'legend right value']/text()").extract()
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to point us at the exact document you're using -- if, for instance, it uses XML namespaces, then  you'd have to change your query to be namespace-aware, or else it'll never find anything. (Is there a `xmlns=` up earlier in your document?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example scrapy shell session with the different phases:

1. fetch the starting page
2. grab the iframe containing the stats you're after, and get it's `src` attribute
3. fetch the corresponding iframe content (this needs another `Request`, in the shell just use `fetch()`)
4. find the table with the data, and pick only rows at even positions
5. in each row, use odd-position cells (1 and 3) for the numbers, and the 2nd cell for the stat name

It goes like this:

```
scrapy shell "http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/08/08/france/ligue-1/stade-de-reims/paris-saint-germain-fc/1686679/?ICID=PL_MS_01"
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-08-21 11:06:19+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/08/08/france/ligue-1/stade-de-reims/paris-saint-germain-fc/1686679/?ICID=PL_MS_01> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fcfe7bda550>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/08/08/france/ligue-1/stade-de-reims/paris-saint-germain-fc/1686679/?ICID=PL_MS_01>
[s]   response   <200 http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/08/08/france/ligue-1/stade-de-reims/paris-saint-germain-fc/1686679/?ICID=PL_MS_01>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fcfe8299ad0>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7fcfe7386b10>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: import urlparse

In [2]: iframe_src = response.css('div.block_match_stats_plus_chart > iframe::attr(src)').extract()[0]

In [3]: fetch(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, iframe_src))
2014-08-21 11:06:35+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://int.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/1686679/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fcfe7bda550>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://int.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/1686679/>
[s]   response   <200 http://int.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/1686679/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fcfe8299ad0>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7fcfe7386b10>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [4]: stats = {}

In [5]: for row in response.css('div.chart > table > tr:nth-child(even)'):
    name = row.css('td:nth-child(even)::text').extract()[0]
    stats[name] = map(int, row.css('td:nth-child(odd)::text').extract())
   ...:     

In [6]: stats
Out[6]: 
{u'Corners': [1, 5],
 u'Fouls': [14, 14],
 u'Offsides': [2, 4],
 u'Shots on target': [2, 8],
 u'Shots wide': [3, 8]}

In [7]:
```

Comment: Thanks alot, will try this later on today.

Comment: Hi I tried and succeded at extracting the iframe src and also fetching the url, but somehow it doesn't let me get past the <tbody>

Comment: In fact, most of the time, in real world web pages, there are no `tbody` elements between `table` and `tr` elements. `tbody` is added by browsers to be clean markup, but then they mess up your XPath with real HTML source. So I would suggest you do not use `tbody` in your XPaths (like I did in the example session above in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath query, I ran it successfully using this [online XPath tool](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)

**Html**

```
<table> 
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">1</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Corners</td>
        <td class="legend right value">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">2</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Shots on target</td>
        <td class="legend right value">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">3</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Shots wide</td>
        <td class="legend right value">8</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">1</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Corners</td>
        <td class="legend right value">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">14</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Fouls</td>
        <td class="legend right value">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">2</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Offsides</td>
        <td class="legend right value">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td class="legend left value">1</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="legend title">Corners</td>
        <td class="legend right value">3</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

**XPath**

```
//td[@class="legend title" and contains(text(), "corner")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

**Result**

```
5
8
3
```